# A function in Google Data Studio that calculates number sessions from a particular source divided to the overall sessions

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I wish to have the percentage of sessions from `facebook.com` to overall sessions and demonstrate it in Google Data Studio. I can show the Facebook trend and compares it to overall by adding a calculated field as follows:

```
CASE WHEN Source = 'facebook.com' THEN 'Facebook' ELSE 'overall' END
```

But I couldn't figure out how to have a calculated filed that shows **the percentage of Facebook sessions** Is there a way to day?

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the type of your metric from number to percent. Just click the  "123" / edit mini button of the metric you need to change. Then under type, select numeric and percent.

[image: Edit metric mini screen]